# How to combine two counts in the same result table in a specific date ranges?

Tags: sql

I am new in sql and I need to calculate the daily average of users clicks in UI. Data I have -> email, 'click' description, and day when this click was made. So to calculate the daily average I need to divide number of daily clicks from number of daily users. Problem is that all my data is a string type. So I tried to use count function in order to get number of clicks and number of users per day.

```
 select day, count (*) as numberOffeatures
    from public.tmp_test_disabled_users
    group by day
    having count(*)>1
    union ALL 
    select day, count (*) numberOfemails
    from public.tmp_test_disabled_users
    group by day
    having count(*)>1
```

But it brings the same values in the same column.

The expectation is to get day then in the separate column number of clicks and then number of users.

Sample data:

```
   +-------------+-------------+---------+
|             |             |         |
| email       | description    day    |
|             |             |         |
+-------------------------------------+
|tst@tst.com  | click1      | 31/08/20|
+-------------------------------------+
|tst@tst.com  | click2      | 31/08/20|
+-------------------------------------+
|tst2@tst.com | click3      | 1/9/20  |
+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

Expected result:

```
   +-----------+-------------------+------------------+
| day       |  numberOfclicks   |  numberOfemails  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|           |                   |                  |
| 31/08/20  |        2          |          1       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|           |                   |                  |
| 1/9/20    |       1           |          1       |
+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result  - as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: Sorry, the first comment :)) just added additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your question @Amber. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @DavidIsla I am using Aginity Pro as a framework to manipulate data I get from connected DB.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need 3 columns with date and numberOffeatures and unique numberOfemails to get the average? if so then you don't need to use UNION ALL.

```
SELECT day, COUNT(numberOffeatures), COUNT(DISTINCT numberOfemails)
FROM public.tmp_test_disabled_users
GROUP BY day
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT numberOfemails)>1
```

or just get the average directly

```
SELECT day, COUNT(numberOffeatures) / COUNT(DISTINCT numberOfemails) AS Average
FROM public.tmp_test_disabled_users
GROUP BY day
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT numberOfemails)>1
```

Comment: numberOffeatures will always be the same as numberOfemails here. Perhaps not what OP wants.

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I was struggling with a combination of two counts. And this is a good example for me as a beginner.

Comment: @Arvind . . . Based on the desired results, the `having` clause is not needed.